my logitech c270 webcam not visible after upgrade to 24.04 (associated with virtualbox attaching the device)
I had a working Logitech C270 webcam. I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 latest a week or so ago. Now, it doesn't seem to be recognized by the kernel.
# dmesg (plug device in)...

[Sat Oct 19 13:28:09 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:09 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825, bcdDevice= 0.10
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:09 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:09 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: SerialNumber: 0FDECE00
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:09 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:11 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:11 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Oct 19 13:28:12 2024] usb 1-2.3.1: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd

# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270

# v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

# ls -l /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory

The device continues to be recognized, but does not work. I've used it with cheese, snapshot and not surprisingly they all report no device. I am in group video and I've run it as root too. I've rebooted. There is no additional drivers available in "Software & Updates".
Any ideas?
UPDATE
I discovered that my VirtualBox PC(s) running was causing the device to not be openable by the host computer. I have disabled the specific device within my VBox configuration(s) and now, my video works, but it does not work within the VBox PC(s). Is there something about VBox that causes the camera to not work on the host? Sure, I can use the device on each VBox instance and on my host computer (not simultaneously obviously).
